# How many animals inhabit the United States?

Tags: ecology, population-biology

How many animals inhabit the United States and its waters? Not the number of species, but the number of individual animals. And since animals are diverse, maybe we can limit the estimate to just vertebrates - domesticated and wild. I totally get that nobody knows the answer to this, but I'm wondering if anyone has made an estimate, or if there are sources from which I could piecemeal an estimate.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_organisms_by_population#Vertebrates) to start calculating a rough estimate.

Comment: Related post: [How many organisms have ever lived on Earth?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6937/how-many-organisms-have-ever-lived-on-earth)

Comment: If you are interested in the number of pets, this can be found here: http://www.aspca.org/animal-homelessness/shelter-intake-and-surrender/pet-statistics (e.g.:It's estimated that 70-80 million dogs and 74-96 million cats are owned in the United States.)

Comment: Do humans count?